# super().__init__(model, year, position) TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'position'

Tags: python

I have a problem. Like that!
code:

```
class Pass:
    def __init__(self, model, color, year, position):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.year = year
        self.position = position

class Car(Pass):
    def __init__(self, model, year, position):
        super().__init__(model, year, position)
        if self.model == "Lacetti":
            self.cost = 138000000 - ((2020 - year) * 5000000)
        elif self.model == "Spark":
            self.cost = 92821000 - ((2020 - year) * 2000000)
        elif self.model == "Malibu":
            self.cost = 311124067 - ((2020 - year) * 3000000)
        else:
            print("Find out the price of the car on the Internet!")

    def malumot(self):
        return "Model: {} Color: {} Year: {} Position: {} Cost: {}".format(
                self.model, self.year, self.position, self.cost
            )
class Full_data(Pass):
    def __init__(self, rusumi, rangi, yili, pozitsiya, carclass):
        super().__init__(rusumi, rangi, yili, pozitsiya)
        if self.model == "Lacetti":
            self.cost = 138000000 - ((2020 - year) * 5000000)
        elif self.model == "Spark":
            self.cost = 92821000 - ((2020 - year) * 2000000)
        elif self.model == "Malibu":
            self.cost = 311124067 - ((2020 - year) * 3000000)
        else:
            print("Find out the price of the car on the Internet!")
        self.classes = carclass
    def data(self):
        return "Model: {} Color: {} Year: {} Position: {} Cost: {}".format(
                self.model, self.year, self.position, self.cost
            )

car_1 = Car("Lacetti", 2018, "3")

print(car_1.model)
print(car_1.year)
print(car_1.position)
print(car_1.cost)
a = car_1.data()
print(a)
```

can you help me?
it says: "**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'position'"
I don't know what is wrong?
Can you give the answer?
Please edit wrong and send it with code!
Thank you!

Comment: The error message could hardly be clearer: "`__init__()` missing 1 required positional argument: `position`". What else do you need to know?

Comment: Your error is too obvious. Are you learning python just now? Your parent class  Pass has a constructor with 4 arguments, and your Car class is calling it with 3.

Answer (score 0):

You've inherited Pass class in Car class and call its init method but you need to send 4 args to Pass class (model, color, year, position) because you haven't defined any of them with a default value. However, in your Car Class, you send only 3 values (args), `super().__init__(model, year, position)` . You forgot to send **color** and python assumes you send position argument in Car Class to Pass Class as its color parameter. Respect to

- Car.model = Pass.model
- Car.year = Pass.year
- Car.position = Pass.color
- Car.?? = Pass.position

```
class Pass:
    def __init__(self, model, color, year, position):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.year = year
        self.position = position

class Car(Pass):
    def __init__(self, model, year, position):
        super().__init__(model, year, position)
```